Elements that are automorphic images
Consider an finite abelian group $G$ and two elements $x,y \in G$. Is there a way to check whether there exists a $\phi \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ such that $\phi(x) = y$?
Here are some necessary conditions for the property to hold that I was able to prove

Consider a positive integer $k$. If there exists in an $a\in G$ such that $a^k = x$, then there exists a $b\in G$ such that $b^k =y$. Furthermore, if there exists a $b\in G$ such that $b^k = y$, then there exists an $a\in G$ such that $a^k=x$.

I feel like the problem is either well known & solved or well know & computationally difficult. Any thoughts/results about this?

Also, $x$ and $y$ must have the same order.

The FTFAG means we only need to solve the problem for $$\prod_n \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}^{k_n}$$

Simultaneously cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472592/elements-that-are-automorphic-images . Please, do not do that.

Call two elements of $G$ equivalent if there is an automorphism $\phi$ mapping one to the other.
By FTFAG we can take
$$G=\prod_i \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{k_i}}$$
and because homomorphisms between groups of coprime order are trivial, any automorphism decomposes into an automorphism for each prime $p$, so we can take a fixed prime and assume
$$G=\prod_i \mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_i}}$$
Now, if $H= \prod_{i=1}^k H_i$ an endomorphism $\phi : H \to H$ is of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11} & \dots &\phi_{1k}\\ \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \phi_{k1} & \dots & \phi_{kk}\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $\phi_{ij}$ is a homomorphism $H_j \to H_i$, where you compute the effect of this on $(h_1 , \dots , h_k)$ just like you would a matrix acting on a vector.
$$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11} & \dots &\phi_{1k}\\ \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \phi_{k1} & \dots & \phi_{kk}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} h_1 \\ \dots \\ h_k \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11}(h_1)+ \dots + \phi_{1k}(h_k) \\ \dots \\ \phi_{k1}(h_1)+ \dots + \phi_{kk}(h_k) \end{pmatrix}$$
I claim that any two elements of maximal order in $G$ are equivalent. To show this, I will show they are all equivalent to $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$ taking wlog the first component in the product to be a cycle of maximal order.
We want to find an invertible matrix satifying
$$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11} & \dots &\phi_{1k}\\ \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \phi_{k1} & \dots & \phi_{kk}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \dots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} g_1 \\ \dots \\ g_k \end{pmatrix}$$
Where $g_i$ is an arbitrary element of $G_i$ such that $g=(g_1,\dots , g_k)$ has maximal order.
Because $g$ is of maximal order, at least one $g_i$ is of maximal order, and $G_i$ is of maximal order. Assume wlog this is $g_1$. This means the order of any $G_i$ divides the order of $G_1$.
Clearly
$$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11} & \dots &\phi_{1k}\\ \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \phi_{k1} & \dots & \phi_{kk}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \dots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11}(1) \\ \dots \\ \phi_{k1}(1) \end{pmatrix}$$
So let's take $\phi_{i1}$ to be the unique homomorphism $G_1 \to G_i$ that maps $1$ to $g_i$, which must exist, as $G_1$ and $G_i$ are cyclic groups and the order of $G_i$ divides the order of $G_1$.
For every other $\phi_{ij}$, I will set it to be the identity automorphism if $i=j$ and the $0$ homomorphism otherwise. I claim the overall matrix $\phi$ this produces is invertible. We just need to check that the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial. Suppose $(x_1,\dots , x_k)$ is in the kernel:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11} & \dots &\phi_{1k}\\ \dots & \dots & \dots \\ \phi_{k1} & \dots & \phi_{kk}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \dots \\ x_k \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \dots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Evaluating, using our definitions of the $\phi_{ij}$ we get
$$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11}(x_1) \\ \phi_{21}(x_1)+x_2 \\ \phi_{31}(x_1)+x_3 \\ \dots \\ \phi_{k1}(x_1)+x_k \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\\dots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$\phi_{11}$ is the endomorphism of a cyclic group mapping $1$ to $g_1$, which is of maximal order, so $\phi_{11}$ is invertible. Hence the first entry tells us $x_1=0$. It immediately follows that all $x_i=0$. So the kernel of $\phi$ is just $(0, \dots , 0)$ meaning $\phi$ is an automorphism, completing the proof that any two elements of $G$ of maximal order are equivalent.
I suspect this method can be extended to show all elements of the same order are equivalent.

It is certainly not true that all elements of the same order are equivalent. E.g., consider the elements $(p,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $C_{p^2}\oplus C_p$.
